# Unable to copy files from remote source folder to local through GPO

Tags: group-policy

I am trying to copy 4 files from one remote folder, accessable from all devices in this intranet, to endusers folders, through a GPO. The remote folder have read only permissions, for every domain user.

From Group Policy Management Editor, I am able to navigate through explorer to that remote folder, in both domain controller as well as on endusers devices.

Here is an image of where I have setup at least one file copy:

[image]

Here I have a part of the GP result (`gpresult /f /h gp.html`) where I got an error(not sure if is related) in the enduser device:

[image]

If I use a local enduser folder as source, it works well.

I am also forcing the GP to be update after every change, in enduser device, through:

```
GPupdate /Force
```

Comment: What do the permissions look like for the shared folder you are trying to copy from? Does the computer account of your test computer or "Domain Computers" have read access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in the "Computer Configuration" area of the GPO, this means that the **computers** accounts will perform the network operations (read a file for example). Not the users accounts.

I think you allowed users to read the source folder, but not the computers. So, you can grant "Domain Computers" read access to the source folder ("Domain Computers" is ["A group that represents all workstations and servers joined to the domain](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-samr/565a6584-3061-4ede-a531-f5c53826504b).")

If you want, you can create a security group by yourself instead and add computers in it as needed (however you'll need to restart the computers after adding them to the group otherwise they won't update their membership).

Comment: Damn such a noob fail, I had the domains users only, and not the domain computers. After giving domain computers permission on remote folder, the GPO was applied on endusers. Thanks a log Swisstone!